# Can Rhino stub out a dictionary so that no matter what key is used the same value comes back?

Tags: rhino-mocks

```
var fakeRoles = MockRepository.GenerateStub < IDictionary<PermissionLevel, string>>();
        fakeRoles[PermissionLevel.Developer] = "Developer";
        fakeRoles[PermissionLevel.DeveloperManager] = "Developer Manager";
```

This is specific to what that method happens to be calling, and is irrelevant for the sake of my unit test.
I'd rather do this:

```
fakeRoles.Stub(r => r[PermissionLevel.None]).IgnoreArguments().Return("Developer");
```

But I get an exception telling me to set the properties directly. Is there a way to tell rhino to just return the same value for any key given to this stub `IDictionary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not a stub (in RhinoMock's understanding), you have to create a mock:

```
var fakeRoles = MockRepository.GenerateMock < IDictionary<PermissionLevel, string>>();
fakeRoles.Expect(r => r[PermissionLevel.None]).IgnoreArguments().Return("Developer");
```

Comment: +1 this works, but why is this called a mock? because it fakes behavior of some sort?

Comment: Hi @Maslow, in RhinoMocks a stub is something very specific - an object that has empty methods returning null and "normal" properties (they return what you assign to them). If you need more logic, you have to create a mock. Essentially its just naming convention.